# JSCONSOLE is up and running but not working due to error 404?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, debugging, remote-debugging

**jsConsole** would be a WONDERFUL tool if I could only get it to work. My code (both on a dev server as well as a public server (cloaked for security) both show 404 errors using the script line:

```
<script src="https://jsconsole.com/js/remote.js?9c43f243-b257-4cef-b56d-de5386fddbcd">
```

As such, it is never making the connection. I tried it in jsBin.com as well but it didn't work (I don't have an account or I would put it there too). There were no errors listed on jsBin.com that I could see. I'm lost...

Here's the procedure that I followed from [HERE](http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html) (my inputs are **bolded**):

**Opened browser to: https://jsconsole.com/**

*Use :help to show jsconsole commands*
*version: 2.1.2*

**:listen 9c43f243-b257-4cef-b56d-de5386fddbcd**

*Connected to "9c43f243-b257-4cef-b56d-de5386fddbcd"*

*>*

It presented me with the following script which I inserted the following two lines

```
<script>console.log("Hello world");</script>
<script src="https://jsconsole.com/js/remote.js?9c43f243-b257-4cef-b56d-de5386fddbcd">
```

into my test code directly above the closing  tag and added the javascript line inside the body like so:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://jsconsole.com/js/remote.js?9c43f243-b257-4cef-b56d-de5386fddbcd"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>console.log("Hello world");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The remote feature is [not supported anymore](https://github.com/remy/jsconsole/issues/101). Unfortunately the documentation lies about it, the `listen` command is still there as if it worked, and the resulting error is not helpful either.

I guess it was good while it lasted.